# System.FinalException: Record is read-only:

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm new to Apex code, got below error
Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger PositionTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: PositionTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only: Trigger.PositionTrigger: line 4, column 1

```
trigger PositionTrigger on Position__c (after insert) {
  Position__c ThePosition = trigger.new[0];
  if(ThePosition.Days_Open__c>90){
    ThePosition.Educational_Requirements__c='Featured';
    update ThePosition;
  }
}
```

please let me know the solution.

Answer (score 5):

When you are doing an After trigger, Trigger.new is read only. If you want to make changes to it, then it is best to do it in a Before trigger.

Also, your trigger is not bulkified. If more than one record is updated at a time, then only the first one will be evaluated. See http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code and search for other examples.